# Issue with Docker container

Tags: typescript, docker, containers

Having a problem with Docker, it's being very weird, I can connect to a Postgres container when I run the app without being in a Docker container, but when I run it inside a container it can not reach the database, the first thought would be adding host.docker.internal which I did and before I updated Docker, that worked, also another weird thing, prisma(database layer) can migrate during the build process but can not connect when the app starts.

Edit: seems it's not enough information, here's the code in question so people can try themselves, might be easier.

https://github.com/NeutronScott12/TheLastHurrah/tree/master/javascript/packages/the-last-hurrah-applications

What's really weird, I have the same setup for another app and it works, check the link above go up one branch and in commence has the same setup, but works.

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@host.docker.internal:5433/thelasthurrah_application?schema=public"

```
 /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:44801
application_service  |             reject(new PrismaClientInitializationError(error2.message, this.config.clientVersion, error2.error_code));
application_service  |                    ^
application_service  |
application_service  | PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5433`
application_service  |
application_service  | Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5433`.
application_service  |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:44801:20 {
application_service  |   clientVersion: '3.15.2',
application_service  |   errorCode: 'P1001'
application_service  |
```

--

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    application-service:
        # network_mode: host
        container_name: 'application_service'
        env_file:
            #     - ./.env.production
            - ./environment/.env
        restart: always
        build: .
        image: application_service
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '4004:4004'
            - '50051:50051'
```

These are in separate files.

```
thelasthurrah_application_database:
        image: onjin/alpine-postgres
        container_name: thelasthurrah_application_database
        restart: always
        expose:
            - '5433'
        ports:
            - '5433:5432'
        volumes:
            - thelasthurrah_application_database:/var/lib/postgresql/data (edited)
```

Comment: The error message says it's trying to contact postgres at `localhost`, so it looks like your `DATABASE_URL` isn't being used. Are you sure you're using the correct variable name, and that it's actually being set inside your container? There's not enough information in the question for us to know.

Comment: Because it's not meant to happen, funnily enough, I have another container that works with the same settings.

It does see the DATABASE_URL as you can see - 

PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5433` 

Outside of the container, it works, and this setup used to work until I updated Docker